Serilog console sink that logs exception message without stacktrace
Some of Serilog's standard template properties can be customised, e.g. {Timestamp:HH:mm:ss}, {Level:u3} and {Message:lj}. Not so for {Exception}, which prints both message and stack trace, on multiple lines.
For the human-readable console sink, a stack trace adds significant noise and friction, especially when tailing a remote docker container which is already ugly (no colour, for example). If I need the stack trace, I would consult a durable sink, e.g. file, Seq.
How can I log just the exception message to the console sink?
(I'm aware of Serilog.Expressions, but for something so simple I hope there's a solution without another dependency.)

As per a comment on the repo, here's a solution using a custom enricher.
Create the enricher ExceptionMessageEnricher.cs:
using Serilog.Core;
using Serilog.Events;

namespace Serilog.Enrichers;

public sealed class ExceptionMessageEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
  public const string PROPERTY_NAME = "ExceptionMessage";

  public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
  {
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(logEvent, nameof(logEvent));
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(propertyFactory, nameof(propertyFactory));

    if (logEvent.Exception == null) return;

    var property = propertyFactory.CreateProperty(PROPERTY_NAME, $"\"{logEvent.Exception.Message}\"");
    logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(property);
  }

}

Then use it in the Serilog config:
var outputTemplate = "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {ExceptionMessage}{NewLine}";

services.AddSerilog((services, config) => config
  // ...
  .WriteTo.Logger(x => x
    .Enrich.With<ExceptionMessageEnricher>()
    .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate:outputTemplate)
  )
);

A rendered message would look something like this:
[13:04:44 ERR] Something bad happened "The exception message"

Notes:

The custom enricher adds an ExceptionMessage property, which is then referenced in the log template
The ExceptionMessage property is not needed in durable sinks (e.g. file, Seq) as they receive the full exception anyway; thus the console sink and custom enricher are defined in a sub-logger - I'm unaware whether there are perf considerations, but I suspect it should be fine
If needed, the console sink can be wrapped in an async sink

An alternative approach, using Serilog.Expressions: {Inspect(@x).Message}.
